# Windows 10 - How do I keep netstat constantly running?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I want to make it so the "netstat" command is constantly running. How do you do that?

Comment: put it in a batch and loop it

Answer (score 4):

Use the interval switch (see below):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You create a batch file for `netstat` using `loop`

```
:loop 
netstat -nao | findstr :80
timeout /T 500
clear
goto loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this command

netstat -an 5

here 5 does the magic for netstat. it represents time interval. so once once completed, it will wait for that much of time e.g. in this case it will wait for 5 seconds. ....cheers

Answer (score 1):

use `--contious` or `-c` for example:

```
netstat -ano -p -c
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).